# How get real raw data over tcp

Tags: node.js, tcpclient, nodejs-stream, raw

I want to retrieve data via TCP, but the data obtained becomes the presence of new lines.
However, if you use other tools such as putty, the results look good.
Where do you think the problem lies.
Thankyou

```
const net = require('node:net');
net.isIP('127.0.0.1'); // returns 4
const client = net.createConnection({ port: 1024 }, () => {
  // 'connect' listener.
  console.log('connected to server!');
  client.write('world!\r\n');
});

// Set encoding for the socket
utf8=client.setEncoding('utf8');

// Handle incoming data
utf8.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log('Received data utf8:', data);
  var rawBuffer = Buffer.from(data);
  console.log('Buffer Data as String:', rawBuffer.toString('utf-8'));
```

Result from my code:
&&

 
0101 
RDG-061 
010 
20 

0103 
1 
0 
1048 
233

0105240

Result from raw Putty (real data): 
0101RDG-061 
01020 
01031 
01044829 
010524030

Comment: What is "client" in your code?

Comment: Please do not use comments to add useful information. Instead, [edit] the post itself (use the "Edit" button beneath the tags on your question). Do take a look at the [formatting guide](/help/formatting) on how to display code well-formatted. Usually a direct copy-paste from your IDE encapsulated in triple-backticks is enough.

Comment: Im using nodejs sir

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's because different OS has different conventions for line endings and hence you might be getting this output. you can use linebuffer and customise it according to your need.

```
let lineBuffer = '';

client.setEncoding('utf8');

client.on('data', (data) => {
  lineBuffer += data;
  while (lineBuffer.includes('\r\n')) {
    const [line, rest] = lineBuffer.split('\r\n', 2);
    console.log('Received data:', line);
    lineBuffer = rest;
  }
});
```

Comment: i think this should work like you want, i tried to customise it according to your output format. let me know